# 2 divs inside a common div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs, 1 of which contains a bunch of text and another which contains a photo inside one common div. I need to stack one of the divs (the one containing the image) on top of the other (The one containing the text). How can I do this with CSS?

Here's the HTML code, if it helps:

````html
```HTML
<div class="division-2">

  <div class="text">
    <h3 class="p4"> X</h3>
    <p class="p">Y</p>
    <p class="p-alt">X</p>
    <p class="Y">Y</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pfp-photo">
    <img src="./pic.png" alt="" class="car">
  </div>

</div>
```
````

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What do you mean by "*stack one on top of the other*," is that vertically on the page (so the image is closer to the address-bar of the browser) or in the Z axis (so the image is 'closer' to the user, hiding the text 'behind' the image)? Also, in your HTML the 'text' `<div>` contains the image `<div>`; you seem to have forgotten to close the first element.

Comment: can you showcase the expected output, not clear from the description?

Comment: if you are just wanting to reverse the order of the text and photo divs, you can just use flex on the container with a flex direction of column reverse

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica What I had in mind was that the div that is .text, I want it to fill up the whole of .it's parent division-2. Keeping in mind that I have another div that is .pfp-photo containing the image with a class of .car .

Comment: @NicoHaase Well, I'm kind of just stuck there, all I wanted was for the the text to go around the image. instead of having just those 2 divs taking up 50% of their parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just move in html elements :

```
    <div class="division-2">
   <div class="pfp-photo">
      <img src="./pic.png" alt="" class="car">
    </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h3 class="p4"> X</h3>
    <p class="p">Y</p>
    <p class="p-alt">X</p>
    <p class="Y">Y</p>
  </div>
```

and to make sure it will work put for class division-2, by giving `display flex` your elements will go next to each other and by `flex-direction: column` the elements will position from top to bottom

```
.division-2 {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: if op can't reverse elements, you should just use `column-reverse` as the flex direction - if they could move the elements, then they don't need flex at all

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position: relative;` to parent and `position: absolute;` to children. Try setting `z-index` to child nodes to addange their position on z axis. Without using `z-index` the image will be placed over the text. Since the image div is coming after the text div

```css
.division-2 {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.pfp-photo {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="division-2">
  <div class="text">
    <h3 class="p4"> X</h3>
    <p class="p">Y</p>
    <p class="p-alt">X</p>
    <p class="Y">Y</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pfp-photo">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" alt="" class="car">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: think the z-indices are back to front?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius added it purposefully, just to make the text visible over the image. Or else the text wont be visible. If that is not needed, that can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the div order in the HTML:

```
<div class="division-2">
  
  <div class="pfp-photo">
    <img src="./pic.png" alt="" class="car">
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <h3 class="p4"> X</h3>
    <p class="p">Y</p>
    <p class="p-alt">X</p>
    <p class="Y">Y</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.division-2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

.pfp-photo {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

.text {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

Add some top margin to the .text div to move it down from the image.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
.division-2{
    positon:relative;
}
.pfp-photo{
    positon:absolute;
    top:0;
}
.text{
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
<div class="division-2">

  <div class="text">
    <h3 class="p4"> X</h3>
    <p class="p">Y</p>
    <p class="p-alt">X</p>
    <p class="Y">Y</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pfp-photo">
    <img src="https://hoanghamobile.com/tin-tuc/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/gg-1.jpg" alt="" class="car">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share more details, such that others can learn from your answer. The given snippet does not look like the expected result from the question after all

Comment: sr.  my mistake. i just edited my answer. This use "position" in css

Comment: Your answer contains only code, not a single line of explanation. Nobody can learn from your answer, as you haven't shared **why** this code could resolve the given problem

Comment: i thank you can read positon in "https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp" to know about "position" in CSS.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it. Don't hide it in the comment section, and also don't just link to any other page